# SHEETOFFSET to copy color

Tags: vba, colors, formatting

I am using the SHEETOFFSET VBA code

```
Function SHEETOFFSET(offset, Ref)
' Returns cell contents at Ref, in sheet offset
Application.Volatile
With Application.Caller.Parent
SHEETOFFSET = .Parent.Sheets(.Index + offset) _
.Range(Ref.Address).Value
End With
End Function
```

And then the following code within within my new sheet

```
=sheetoffset(-1, B2)
```

to copy the value of cell B2 in the previous sheet to my new sheet.

However, I also need to copy the color of that particular cell. Is there any code that I can enter in the original VBA code above to do this? Or is there another way of achieving this?

Many thanks for your help
Tim

Comment: You want the above function to color the cell as well?

Comment: Hi Siddharth, Yes that's correct. The values are copying across fine, but I want the cell colors to copy across as well. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes it is possible but you will have to use worksheet_change event in tandem with your above function. It's kind of complicated but do-able.

Comment: Is the worksheet_change event VBA code? If so will it be valid for all the sheets within my workbook? I don't know VBA that well but would appreciate if you are able to walk me through it?

Comment: Sure gimme few minutes. let me post an answer.

Comment: And just to clarify, there are some cells that are uncolored and these need to stay uncolored, and the ones that have a fill in them need to be copied to my new sheet.

Comment: I am sure you can take care of rest of the requirements once you understand the logic ;)

Answer (score 1):

**Logic**:

1. Define a `Public` variable to hold the color of the cell
2. In `Worksheet_Change` check if the above variable has any value. If yes then change the color of the target cell.
3. Once the above is done, reset the variable to 0

**Code in Module**:

```
Public cellColor As Double

Function SHEETOFFSET(offset, Ref)
    With Application.Caller.Parent
        SHEETOFFSET = .Parent.Sheets(.Index + offset) _
        .Range(Ref.Address).Value

        '~~> Store the color in a variable
        cellColor = .Parent.Sheets(.Index + offset) _
        .Range(Ref.Address).Interior.ColorIndex
    End With
End Function
```

**Code in Sheet Code Area**:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim aCell As Range

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    For Each aCell In Target.Cells
        If cellColor <> 0 Then aCell.Interior.ColorIndex = cellColor
    Next

Letscontinue:
    cellColor = 0
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Letscontinue
End Sub
```

**ScreenShot**:

[image]

**My Personal Thoughts**:

1. I am **not in favor** of the `SHEETOFFSET` function in the first place because the formula is actually referring a cell in the current sheet. Any changes, for example, deletion of that cell will error out your formula
2. It is better to link the cells directly

**FOLLOWUP (From Comments)**

You can run this code in the end to refresh all formulas.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range, aCell As Range

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        Set rng = Nothing

        On Error Resume Next
        Set rng = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            For Each aCell In rng
                aCell.Formula = aCell.Formula
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: @user2337691: I have updated the above post with a code which you can run to refresh all the formulas. See the FOLLOWUP.

Comment: no in the module. you can call this from a button in your master sheet?

Comment: Cool, I have added a button and assigned the macro to it, however when I click it it comes up with a runtime error: 1004. When I choose to debug it the line of code    aCell.Formula = aCell.Formula is highlighted in yellow in VB

Comment: Debug that line and see what is the value of `aCell.Formula`

Comment: When I hover over that line it says "=#REF!A367" with the quotation marks included?

Comment: when you debug that line, type this in the immediate window `?ws.name` and then type `?acell.address` that will tell you what cell is this. go to that cell. that cell has an incorrect formula.

Comment: Siddharth you are a genius. Thanks so much for your help. Perfect!! :-)